# process.platform and os.arch() give out wrong results

Tags: node.js

`process.platform` gives out `'win32'` and os.arch() gives out `'ia32'`, despite my system being actually 64-bit, according to the settings. Why is this?

Comment: `IA-32` means that you are running the x86 32-bit version of NodeJS. Maybe reinstall Node and make sure you install the 64-bits version

Comment: @Seblor Tried that, same thing happens. Well, I downloaded the 64-bit binary and just installed it over the existing one.